# Door is opened vs Door is open vs Door open

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I know that the 1st one is a passive voice, 2nd is a state of the door (which is opened) and opened here is an adjective, right? But when do we use the 3rd one? I'm pretty sure that I've seen it somewhere but can't get the area of usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third example could be used as a command

> **Door open!**

or 
may be used to describe the state of the door

> The car drove away with its **door open**.

Comment: A gentleman held the door open so the ladies could enter the shop.

Answer (score 0):

> ... door is opened

You are right, **opened** is a past participle, which is used after **is** to indicate passive voice. An example sentence might be

> If the door is opened, the alarm will sound.

Note that, for some verbs, the past participle has the same form as the corresponding adjective, for example **broken**. You can't assume that something that looks like a past participle after **is**, actually is a past participle.

---

> ... door is open

Here, open is used as an predicative adjective - after the verb. here is an example sentence:

> The door is **open**.

---

> ... door open

Here, open is used as an attributive adjective. Attributive adjectives usually go before the noun:

> The **open** door shifted back and forth in the wind.

In some cases, an attributive adjective can go after a noun, as in this sentence.

> He held the door **open** as I approached.

[This article](https://www.englishgrammar.org/attributive-adjectives-nouns/) explains describes some situations where an attributive adjective can go after the noun.

Comment: I have read sentences like 'the door opened with a squeaking sound'... implying that noone opened it..it opened on its own or perhaps by wind. So what kind of sentence is it when it should be in passive voice but it is written in active voice?

Comment: @RADS what do you mean by "when it should be in passive voice but it is written in active voice"? Can you describe a situation where that might happen?

Comment: Sorry for not describing it well. We find sentences like 'Shop opens at 9 AM.' written on the entrance door of many shops. What I mean is that Shop doesn't open itself...in reality it is opened by a person at 9 AM. But the first sentence is written in active voice and 'the shop' is not the doer of the action, it is patient of the verb 'open'. So why it is in active voice not in passive. Someone told me that these sentences are called Quasi-passive. But I doubt so I'm here to ask and get more clear picture on it.

Comment: @RADS According to the Cambdrige Dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/open , the meaning of **open** relating to a shop of office means "start to do business". That is something that the shop can be considered to do by itself- "the bank opens at 9am". The word can also be used transitively "Ahmed opens his coffee shop at 9am".  As this ngram graph shows, the intransitive usage is nearly three times as common as the tranisitive usage https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+shop+opens%2C+opens+the+shop&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26